# Referencing an object created in main method in nested class Java

Tags: java, class, methods, nested

I am new to java and having some difficulty with nesting classes. I create an instance of my inner class in the main method (comp1) but when I try to reference it in another method that prints output (doCompOutput), I get an error that it cannot find the symbol comp1 or the method doCompOutput

```
public class Team{

private  String teamName;
private  String name1, name2, name3, name4;

public Team(String _teamName, String _name1, String _name2, String _name3, String _name4){
    setTeam(_teamName, _name1, _name2, _name3, _name4);
}
public void setTeam(String _teamName, String _name1, String _name2, String _name3, String _name4){
    teamName = _teamName;
    name1 = _name1;
    name2 = _name2;
    name3 = _name3;
    name4 = _name4;
}
***TEAM GET METHODS REMOVED TO SHORTEN CODE***

public static void doTeamOutput(){
    System.out.println(team1.getTeamName() + team1.getName1() + team1.getName2() + team1.getName3() + team1.getName4());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Team team1 = new Team("Spartans", "chase", "mark", "matt", "jake");
    doTeamOutput();
    Team team2 = new Team("Warriors", "john", "paul", "george", "ringo");
    doTeamOutput();
    Competition comp1 = new Competition("Alpha","Spartans","Warriors",2013);
    doCompOutput();
}

static class Competition {
    String compName;
    String winner;
    String runner;
    int year;

    public Competition(String _compName, String _winner, String _runner, int _year){
        setComp(_compName, _winner, _runner, _year); //set
    }
    public void setComp(String _compName, String _winner, String _runner, int _year){
        compName = _compName;
        winner = _winner;
        runner = _runner;
        year = _year;
    }
    public static void doCompOutput(){
        System.out.println(comp1.getName());
     }
    public String getName()
        return compName;

    ***COMP GET METHODS MOVED TO SHORTED CODE***    
}
```

}

Comment: `doTeamOutput` won't compile either because `team1` variable is not declared in the method and is not a parameter. You may have a similar issue in `doCompOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doCompOutput() is trying to call the method getName() on an object that the compiler doesn't know.

```
public static void doCompOutput(){
    System.out.println(this.getName());
}
```

With that code, the method will output the `compName` of the object you call the method on.

Your code has a lot of mistakes. You should look up some tutorials about [the basics of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)